# Cypress UI tests throwing time out for waiting for browser

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am running Cypress UI tests in `AzureDevOps` CI/CD and some how most of the UI test are getting failed. All of the tests were running fine few days back. 
It is throwing a `Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying.` error: Any advise on how to resolve the issue.

**Environment Details:**
Cypress version: 3.4.1,
Node: 10.x,
Azure DevOps CI/CD

```
Running: report/send-report.spec.js...                         (12 of 14) 
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0294852Z 
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0295427Z Warning: Cypress can only record videos when using the built in 'electron' browser.
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0295707Z 
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0296579Z You have set the browser to: 'chrome'
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0296837Z 
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0297613Z A video will not be recorded when using this browser.
2019-10-10T00:47:31.0313740Z (node:4030) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2019-10-10T00:48:01.0316223Z 
2019-10-10T00:48:01.0592004Z Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying...
2019-10-10T00:48:31.0587550Z 
2019-10-10T00:48:31.0839142Z Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying again...
2019-10-10T00:49:01.0877330Z 
2019-10-10T00:49:01.1241198Z The browser never connected. Something is wrong. The tests cannot run. Aborting...
```

Comment: Would it possibly because chrome is not installed? Have you tried electron browser?

Comment: @Pigbrainflower No its is installed.. till last week, this was working fine. I could see all of the installation steps are successfull and haven't changed any CI/CD tasks.

Comment: Do you think clearing of the `AppData` from the cypress/production folder makes any difference..

Comment: Is electron browser working? I've seen some issues in github having this error message. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3310, https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1598. Have you read this and try?

Comment: This is my existing command `"cy:test-soccer-app": "set CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 && npm run get-token-soccerapp && cypress run -P cypress-soccerapp -app --env configFile=soccerapp -app --browser chrome"` ..so should i change to following to try in electron ?  `"cy:test-soccer-app": "set CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 && npm run get-token-soccerapp && cypress run -P cypress-soccerapp -app --env configFile=soccerapp -app"`

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that you have set retries value as 2 to enable immediately retry on failure instead of moving on to the next test. So I recommend you to change the value and check if the error still occur.

And you can try another workaround, to change `numTestsKeptInMemory` down from 50 to something sane like `1` or `0`. Here is the offical documentation. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global

In addition, it seems like an occasional error. Because some users failed on the first pipeline, but succeed on the second pipeline. And this should be a problem with cypress itself or your system's memory, you can report this problem to cypress directly.

Here is the link about cypress-io/cypress. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/

And here is the link about the same error message.https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1305

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this same issue and after a long research I've identified that my problem is related to webpack build, so I've tried to build(`npm run build`) and my webpack run out of memory(WSL), I've 32GB of RAM and this still happends, so I just run this `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` and cypress work again, took me some months to discover this as cypress doesn't stop or show errors related to webpack build(just when succeed). Hope I can help you(I've never found that related solution).